# How to make subsequent animation?

Tags: android

```
animatingview=0;
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
    ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
final ConstraintLayout s=findViewById(R.id.editprofileheadid);

while(animatingview<s.getChildCount()){

    s.getChildAt(animatingview).startAnimation(scaleAnimation);

    animatingview++;
}
```

I successfully created the animation for all view in my constraint layout but all the view are animating at the same time, I need all the view to be animated one after another, I tried **Sleep** but I didn't get that luck

Answer (score 1):

Use `setAnimationListener` on your animation to start the next animations in `onAnimationEnd`. You'd basically want to do something along the following lines,

```
    animatingview=0;
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.2f, 1f, 0.2f, 1f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    scaleAnimation.setDuration(600);
    final ConstraintLayout s=findViewById(R.id.editprofileheadid);

    scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if(animatingview<s.getChildCount()){
            //Subsequent animations are started here
            s.getChildAt(animatingview).startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
            animatingview++;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });

    //First view animation is started here
    s.getChildAt(animatingview).startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Comment: that  doesn't work sir, they are animating irrelvently